# The insert query in stored procedure is not running

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The insert query in my stored procedure is not running.
No error occurs but Query fails to insert record.
May i know what is the issue?

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `trip`(IN trip INT, IN rate INT, IN remark VARCHAR(1000))
    BEGIN
        UPDATE booking SET STATUS = "2" WHERE TRIP= trip;   

        SELECT rate AS RATE, remark AS REMARK, t.DRIVER_ID = @driver_id FROM trip_offer t WHERE t.TRIP = trip;

        INSERT INTO rating(TRIP_ID, U_ID, RATE, REMARK, CRT_TMS) VALUES(trip, @driver_id, rate, remark, now());
    END
```

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi the insert query is not running. No new record added into the table.

Comment: Then say : No error occurs but Query fails to insert record. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have several issues.

One definite problem is that MySQL cannot distinguish between variables (parameters to the stored procedure) and columns.  You should *always* use a prefix for variables.  Second, it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do.  This is my best guess:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `trip`(
    IN p_trip INT,
    IN p_rate INT,
    IN p_remark VARCHAR(1000))
BEGIN
    UPDATE booking SET STATUS = "2" WHERE TRIP = v_trip;   

    INSERT INTO rating(TRIP_ID, U_ID, RATE, REMARK, CRT_TMS) 
        SELECT t.trip, t.driver_id, v_rate, v_remark, now()
        FROM trip_offer t
        WHERE t.TRIP = v_trip;
END;$$

DELIMITER $$
```

Comment: i need a separate select query for select because this stored procedure will return the select result.

Answer (score 0):

Issues :

- `t.DRIVER_ID = @driver_id` in `SELECT` is wrong.
- `@driver_id` does not seem to be defined.